# Flutter - Error compiling application after upgrading Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've had problems compiling my application since I upgraded Flutter from v1.9.1+hotfix.2 to v1.14.7-pre.113. I've looked online for a few days now and I haven't been able to find anybody who's getting the same problem. I don't really know what's wrong and I can't seem to find anything, I'm hoping someone who comes across this might know what's wrong.

This is the error I'm getting in the debug console:

```
Compiler message:
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage_image-0.4.0/lib/firebase_storage_image.dart:54:24: Error: The method 'FirebaseStorageImage.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(FirebaseStorageImage key) =>
                       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:489:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').
  ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 803

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 40s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Here's my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: orders_app
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  flutter_signin_button: ^1.0.0
  provider: ^4.0.3
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
  firebase_storage_image: ^0.4.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.1.1

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: can you share code where you are using firebase_storage_image?

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a while but I post this answer for those whom come across this issue

You just need to Upgrade `image_provider` and `firebase_storage_image` to a newer version
from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) and run `pub get`

Answer (score 0):

You should see what new version of Flutter needs Gridel. So you better create a new project with a new version of Flutter then see what changes have been made to your project in the build.gradle , gradle-wrapper.properties , gradle.properties files.
and use *`flutter clean`*.